# Deleting the row of HTML table using tr.remove(), submit button is sending back only rows above it and not below it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have a HTML table for which i have delete button for each row.
Clicking on the delete button, it goes to javascript and I remove the row using below code . When I try to submit the table content back to the controller using the submit (Ajax.beginform), it is sending back the data only above the deleted row, and nothing below the deleted row. Even though in the UI, it is still showing all the rows above and below the deleted row.

Example: Lets say if I upload 3 documents, and delete the middle one, it will remove the row from the table but when I click on the Upload button, I get only the first row.

But if I delete the last row, 3rd document, then I am getting back above 2 documents properly in my Upload button action.

Thanks in advance for your help

javascript code:

```
function removeDocument(selector) {    
    $(selector).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

HTML code:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Upload", "MatterFiling", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "SuccessUploadDocument", OnFailure = "OnUploadFailure" }))
    {

        <table class="table table-bordered" id="DocumentTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><span class="reqAsterisk">* </span>Document Title</th>               
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%; display:none" class="nr" >                            
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => Model.FileName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dmm-autoresize", @rows = "1" })                            
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a style="color:red; cursor:pointer" onclick="removeDocument(this)">
                                <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" value="Upload" id="UploadDocsButton" class="btn btn-primary"/> 
    }
```

[This is after deleting the row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxXV1.png)

[This is before deleting the row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5DYZ.png)

Comment: Please include all relevant code(Html), without, its hard to pinpoint the problem

Comment: sure. I will edit the question

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: If you post the data without deleting a row, can you see everything?

Comment: Yes, I am getting everything back if I am not deleting any thing.

Comment: Lets say if I upload 3 documents, and delete the middle one, it will remove the row from the table but when I click on the Upload button, I get only the first row.

But if I delete the last row, 3rd document, then I am getting back above 2 documents properly in my Upload button action.

Comment: It seems like your html table is breaking down, try delete a row and inspect the table and make sure that the table is 100% valid table struckture

Comment: I have updated the images of the table inspect mode, nothing seems off.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using form then you have refresh your form, you can also try to name the input types name with array like username[].